# Cash change program using loops and if/else

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, do-while

Coding a program that allows user to input a cash amount up to $200.00 and then computes and prints its value in the following denominations (20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01). I think I've figured out the basics of how to get the denominations (division/modulus), but it's the structure of the do/while and if/else that's giving me trouble. I keep getting an error that I need a while statement even though I've entered it and its condition (seen below), but I also am at a bit of a loss as to where to put a range prompt (if the user inputs something negative or above 200). Any suggestions/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
double amt_ent;
    int twenty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime, nickel, penny, remainder;

    printf ("Enter a dollar amount up to $200.00:");
    scanf ("%lf", &amt_ent);

  do
  { printf ("Name - Assignment 2 - Change-O-Matic\n");
      printf ("Amount entered: $%.2lf\n", ((amt_ent*100)/100));
      printf ("Change breakdown:\n");

      { /*Change in twenties*/
      twenty= (int) amt_ent/20;
      if (twenty >= 2)
      printf("%i\t$20.00s\n", twenty);
      if (twenty == 1)
      printf ("%i\t$20.00\n", twenty);
      else 

     /*Change in tens*/
      remainder = twenty % 20;
      ten = remainder/10;

      if (ten >=2)
      printf ("%i\t$10.00s\n", ten);
      if (ten == 1)
      printf ("%i\t$10.00\n", ten);
      else 

    /*Change in fives*/
     remainder = ten % 10;
     five = remainder/10;

     if (five >= 2)
     printf ("%i\t$5.00s\n", five);
     if (five == 1)
     printf ("%i\t$5.00\n", five);
     else 

    /*Change in ones*/
     remainder = five % 5;
     one = remainder/1;

     if (one >= 2)
     printf ("%i\t$1.00s\n", one);
     if (one == 1)
     printf ("%i\t$1.00\n", one);
     else 

    /*Change in quarters*/
     remainder = one % 1;
     quarter = remainder/.25;

     if (quarter >= 2)
     printf ("%i\t$.25s\n", quarter);
     if (quarter == 1)
         printf ("%i\t$.25\n", quarter);
     else

    /*Change in dimes*/
     remainder = quarter % 4;
     dime = remainder/.10;

     if (dime >= 2)
     printf ("%i\t$.10s\n", dime);
     if (dime == 1)
     printf ("%i\t$.10\n", dime);
     else

    /*Change in nickels*/
    remainder = dime % 10;
          nickel = remainder/.05;

          if (nickel >= 2)
              printf ("%i\t$.05s\n", nickel);
          if (nickel == 1)
              printf ("%i\t$.05\n", nickel);
          else 

    /*Change in pennies*/
              remainder = nickel % 20;
          penny = remainder/100;

          if (penny >= 2)
              printf ("%i\t$.01s\n", penny);
          if (penny == 1)
              printf ("%i\t$.01\n", penny);
      }

    while ((amt_ent <= 200.00) && (amt_ent >= 00.00));}

return 0;
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this is for an intro course. We haven't learned arrays yet.

Comment: i think you need to add   these statement  `printf ("Enter a dollar amount up to $200.00:");`
   `scanf ("%lf", &amt_ent);` in `do..while`

Comment: Tried that earlier. The program keeps repeating while only computing the $20.00 portion still. Perhaps a do/while isn't the way to go? I just want it executed once with a prompt to try it again with a new input after.

Comment: Note: 1) `((amt_ent*100)/100)`  does nothing useful.  If you want to round the number entered to the nearest 0.01, do `amt_ent = round(amt_ent*100)/100;`  2) Suggest major re-write and do all internal calculations in cents.  `amt_ent_cts = round(amt_ent*100);` and then use the integer value `amt_ent_cts` for the rest of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As regarding you error, there is extra brace present after `printf ("Change breakdown:\n");`.
And you need not to put closing brace after while statement. `while ((amt_ent <= 200.00) && (amt_ent >= 00.00));}` Remove that also.

For you valid amount handling problem, there is a **`continue`** command which skips the remaining loop and reiterate from beginning when encountered. You can use that.

```
do
  { 
      printf ("Enter a dollar amount up to $200.00:");
      scanf ("%lf", &amt_ent);
      if(amount_ent < 00.00 || amount_ent>200.00)
           continue;
      printf ("Name - Assignment 2 - Change-O-Matic\n");
      printf ("Amount entered: $%.2lf\n", ((amt_ent*100)/100));
      printf ("Change breakdown:\n");
```

If amount entered is invalid, the `continue` statement will execute and remains loop is skipped. Then `printf ("Enter a dollar amount up to $200.00:");` will be executed. So you can see, user wont be able to go ahead of continue unless he enters correct value of amount.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Tested and it works.
You problem was in the way reminder was being calculated. You need to divide the amt_ent again with previous step. Again all % operations work only with integers. So you need to convert your double to integer domain by multiplying with 100 before proceeding with calculations.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
double amt_ent1;
int amt_ent;
int twenty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime, nickel, penny;
do
{ 
    printf ("Enter a dollar amount up to $200.00:");   //<== it is put in due to get the statement again else it execute with the same value.
    scanf ("%lf", &amt_ent1);
    amt_ent = (amt_ent1*100)/100;
    printf ("Name - Assignment 2 - Change-O-Matic\n");
    printf ("Amount entered: $%.2lf\n", amt_ent1);
    printf ("Change breakdown:\n");

    if ((amt_ent > 200.00) || (amt_ent < 00.00)) continue;

    amt_ent = amt_ent1 * 100;
    { /*Change in twenties*/
    twenty= (int) amt_ent/2000;
    if (twenty >= 2)
        printf("%i\t$20.00s\n", twenty);
    if (twenty == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$20.00\n", twenty);

        /*Change in tens*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 2000;
    ten = amt_ent/1000;


    if (ten >=2)
        printf ("%i\t$10.00s\n", ten);
    if (ten == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$10.00\n", ten);

        /*Change in fives*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 1000;
    five = amt_ent/500;

    if (five >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$5.00s\n", five);
    if (five == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$5.00\n", five);

        /*Change in ones*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 500;
    one = amt_ent/100;

    if (one >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$1.00s\n", one);
    if (one == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$1.00\n", one);

        /*Change in quarters*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 100;
    quarter = amt_ent/25;

    if (quarter >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$.25s\n", quarter);
    if (quarter == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$.25\n", quarter);

    /*Change in dimes*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 25;
    dime = amt_ent/10;

    if (dime >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$.10s\n", dime);
    if (dime == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$.10\n", dime);

        /*Change in nickels*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 10;
    nickel = amt_ent/5;

    if (nickel >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$.05s\n", nickel);
    if (nickel == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$.05\n", nickel);

        /*Change in pennies*/
    amt_ent = amt_ent % 5;
    penny = amt_ent/1;

    if (penny >= 2)
        printf ("%i\t$.01s\n", penny);
    if (penny == 1)
        printf ("%i\t$.01\n", penny);
    }
}

while ((amt_ent <= 2000) && (amt_ent >= 0));  //<== it is put inside the do loop it is wrong, it come outside the do lopp.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! quick follow up, where would I put the prompt for re-enter (say if the user input a number not within the range)? Would that go outside the dowhile loop or within in it? (sorry, i know this is a bit rudimentary but i'm pretty new at this) anything helps! thanks!

Comment: Just change if ((amt_ent > 200.00) || (amt_ent < 00.00)) continue; to contain the re-entry prompt if ((amt_ent > 200.00) || (amt_ent < 00.00)) { printf(Invalid input re-try\n"); continue;}

Comment: You may also need exit criteria, such as enter 0 to quit