# How can I make my C program return change in dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies?

Tags: c, int, calculator

Code is :

```
int main()
{
    displayOwe(getOwe(), customerpaid());
    displayChange(dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
    return 0;
}

float getOwe()
{
    float owed;
    printf("\nHow much does the customer owe? ");
    scanf("%f" ,&owed );    
    return owed;
}

float customerpaid()
{
    float paid;
    printf("\nHow much did the customer pay? ");            
    scanf("%f" ,&paid );
    return paid;
}

float calculateTotal (float paid, float owed)
{
    float answer;
    answer = paid - owed;
    return answer;
}

float displayOwe(float owed , float paid)
{   
    printf("\nCustomer owes $%0.2f and paid $%0.2f.", owed, paid);
}

int displayChange(int dollars, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies)
{
    dollars= ;
    quarters=
    dimes=
    nickels=
    pennies=
    printf("\n\nCashier should refund %d dollars, %d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, and %d pennies.", dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies); 
}
```

I have to create a C program to calculate change that shows how much the customer owes and how much the customer paid. I did that part and it is working flawlessly but I do not know how to make the program to show how many dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies the cashier needs to return to the customer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please take your time to format the code to make it _human readable_.

Comment: Hi, What is wrong with it?I posted it as code.

Comment: Um, a little bit of formatting, please. We're not compilers, right?

Comment: Is that better? I removed some of it

Comment: You just need to break it down in steps, largest denomination to smallest.  The answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032680/cash-change-program-using-loops-and-if-else

Answer (score 1):

displayChange needs two extra arguments - float owed, float paid. The other parameters should be references "&" since they are output parameters.

Inside displayChange I would convert the float to ints:

```
int iOwed = owed * 100;  
int iPaid = paid * 100;
```

Now a penny is 1, not 0.01 and a dollar is 100, not 1;

Once you have them as ints, start by getting the change:

```
int change = iPaid - iOwed;
```

Then get how many of each are owed by going from largest to smallest monetary unit - first dividing, then getting the remainder.

```
dollars =  change / 100;
```

Use the modulus operator to get the remainder:

```
remainder  = change % 100;
```

Then continue to calculate the remaining values by using 25, 10, 5 and 1 for quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies.

```
quarters = remainder / 25;

remainder = remainder % 25;
```

Comment: I'm getting numbers that are too big.